# i want to export my cloudformation resources and import in other cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, devops, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

this is my output section code of cloud-formation template for export, i try to export this code and import on other template but this is now work

```
Outputs:
  VpcId:
    Description: Id of VPC
    Value: !Ref VPC
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-MainVPC

  MainVPCCidrBlock:
    Description: CIDR Range for the MainVPC
    Value: !Ref MainVpcCIDR
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-MainVpcCIDR
```

above code for export and this code is not running

what changes do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Although it’s not clear what you mean by ‘ it’s not running’ I’m guessing that the problem is that the output values aren’t being exported in the stack properly. If that is the case

Have you tried encasing your string with " like below.  Everything else looks fine.

```
Outputs:
  VpcId:
    Description: Id of VPC
    Value: !Ref VPC
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-MainVPC"

  MainVPCCidrBlock:
    Description: CIDR Range for the MainVPC
    Value: !Ref MainVpcCIDR
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-MainVpcCIDR"
```